# Implementing of MediaPlayer and MediaTimeline in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, windows-media-player

I have problem with implementing MediaPlayer with MediaTimeline.

MediaPlayer alone - works, code example:

```
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
 player.Open(uri);
 player.Play();
```

But i want to read playback time, seek to exact fragment and add functions like repeating to my program.

Code like:

```
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
 MediaTimeline _mTimeline = new MediaTimeline(uri);
 player.Clock = _mTimeline.CreateClock(true) as MediaClock;
 player.Clock.Controller.Begin();
```

Doesn't work. player.Clock.CurrentState reports "Stopped". I dont have any ideas left to test. What is the problem, and why ClockController doesn't want to start?

Comment: Those classes seem to be more tied to Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) then WinForms. That the first code works is probably sheer luck.

Comment: Yeah, you can be right....

Comment: As noted above, you are using WPF components in Winforms. This can be done, but requires a little extra work. See marked duplicate.